# PHP Format Number With Dollar Sign And Comma And ROUND()

Tags: php, rounding

I have been using this syntax

```
print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->DollarValue) . "</td>";
```

Which will output something like this: `$8812` I want the format to be `$8,812` so I tried this

```
print "<td>" . "$" . round(number_format($res->AveragePrice)) . "</td>";
```

but that did not do the trick either.

What I am after is rounding with a dollar sign and comma, but no decimals.
Further Examples

```
1000.78 -> $1,001
1000.23 -> $1,000
```

What is the php synatx for this?

Comment: `round` the value first before using the `number_format`